# I have this problem when i run my project any solution?

Tags: flutter

Launching lib\main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)

Compiler message:
../../../../../Programs/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/extended_image-0.5.3/lib/src/gesture/extended_image_slide_page_route.dart:331:9: Error: No named parameter with the name 'animation'.
        animation: animation,
        ^^^^^^^^^
../../../../../Programs/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/cupertino/route.dart:436:3: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
  CupertinoFullscreenDialogTransition({
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

Compiler message:
../../../../../Programs/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/extended_image-0.5.3/lib/src/gesture/extended_image_slide_page_route.dart:331:9: Error: No named parameter with the name 'animation'.
        animation: animation,
        ^^^^^^^^^
../../../../../Programs/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/cupertino/route.dart:436:3: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
  CupertinoFullscreenDialogTransition({
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Target kernel_snapshot failed: Exception: Errors during snapshot creation: null
build failed.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script 'E:\from F\Programs\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 896
- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.

  > Process 'command 'E:\from F\Programs\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 3s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited (sigterm)

**I have this problem when i run my project any solution?**

Comment: Please provide the code that is producing the error and how the error is occurring

Comment: I post all the error message  and I didn't get the error location

Answer (score 0):

Check this file: extended_image_slide_page_route.dart at line 331

Your error: *" No named parameter with the name 'animation'."*

you don't have a parameter called 'animation'.

Comment: That file is not internal to my project it is may be in third party library